# How to cast numeric types?

Tags: ios, swift, casting, swift-playground, typecasting-operator

I am using Xcode playground to **downcast** in **swift**. Typecasting would normally allow me to convert a type to derived type using As operator in swift. But it gives me error while i try to typecast var a as Double,String. Thanks in advance!!

```
   var a = 1
   var b = a as Int
   var c = a as Double
   var d = a as String
```

Comment: oh sorry i was saying about downcasting...i think what you say is typecast.So how are we going to perform that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot cast it to each other because they do not relate. You can only cast types that are related like `UILabel` and `UIView` or `[AnyObject]` and `[String]`. Casting an `Int` to a `Double` would be like trying to cast a `CGPoint` to a `CGSize`

So to change for example an `Int` to a `Double` you have to make a new `Double` of that `Int` by doing `Double(Int)`.

This applies to all numeric types like `UInt Int64 Float CGFloat` etc.

Comment: So, i am really confused on why to use downcasting, if i am not able to cast types to unrelated type? and by the way what do you mean to say that you can only cast to related types?

Comment: @rintaro Haha I didnt notice that type, thanks Ill edit it x)

Comment: @anishparajuli What I mean is that in Swift (which is really strict on types) you cant just cast something that is not a child of the type you're trying to cast into.

Comment: Thats where my example comes in to describe, you can cast UILabel to UIView because UILabel is a subclass of UIView, and you can't cast CGPoint to a CGSize because CGPoint is not subtype of any kind to CGSize or the other way around which makes them not related.

Comment: yah now i got the point..if i want to downcast there should be a level of hierarchy between classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a = 1
var b = Int(a)
var c = Double(a)
var d = String(a)
```

Comment: I posted this, before the question got edited from "typecasting" to "downcasting"

Answer (score 0):

Cast as Int works, because `a` is Int

You should do it like this:

```
var c = Double(a)
var d = toString(a) //or String(a)
```